# Selenium Java - Chrome 83. 0 - Authentication required. Basic Authentication required. Unable to login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication, windows-authentication

Trying to login to my application. It shows authentication required pop up.

1. How to avoid Authentication required pop up. Is there any way to avoid it.
   tried options.addarguements.

   ```
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    options.addArguments("enable-automation");
   ```
2. Also passed credentials thru https:username:password@url but did not work.

Is there any method which works. Whats best.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing username and password as python f string.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path="C://downloads//chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("url")
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())

# "Switch" to the Alert browser
alert = Alert(driver)

# Send the username, TAB then password together 
alert.send_keys(f'username{Keys.TAB}password')
alert.accept()
```

Comment: No. It did not work. Do you have any code in java instead of python @shaista-ambreen

Comment: String testURL = "https://" + "admin" + ":" + "pass" + "@" + "stackoverflow.com/"; driver.get(testURL); have you tried passing username and password this way?